# Jquery selector with variable in timed loop is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am trying to do a simple loop with a timer to have some images fade out. The images are being selected through jquery and have the .bgimages class. I have 4 of them and I want to loop through them by using the nth-of-type. I got my loop with the timer working, but for some reason I can't get my iteration number variable running on that jquery selector. It works fine if I switch it for a number, but it just does not want to play with the variable. Here is my code:

```
(function intro (i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   if(i--) {
    $(".bgimages:nth-of-type(i)").fadeOut();
    intro(i);
   }
 }, 3000);
})(4);
```

I tried separating the variable with "" but that did not work. Like so:

```
$(".bgimages:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").fadeOut();
```

It did not work. Also tried declaring the variable just before and turning it into a string.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: .fade() is not available in jquery. Try adding fadeout to  your revised edition

Comment: `$(".bgimages").eq(i).fadeOut()`.  (Also, is your classname literally ".bgimages", or is it "bgimages"?)

Comment: "bgimages", already got it working with first answer. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work with `$(".bgimages:nth-of-type(" + i + ")")` and `fadeOut()` -- although your usage of `i--` would make it skip the 4th one (corrected in my code below)

```js
(function intro (i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   if(i) {
    $(".bgimages:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").fadeOut();
    intro(--i);
   }
 }, 3000);
})(4);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bgimages">A</div>
<div class="bgimages">B</div>
<div class="bgimages">C</div>
<div class="bgimages">D</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!